# tkinter: How to get value from ComboBox in one frame with button in different frame

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

The goal is to allow the user to select from the combobox dropdown and then click Select Files button. The button will get the product type (the value from the combobox) and will open the correct directory based on what is chosen in the combobox. Problem is, I cannot seem to get this value since the button and combobox are in different frames. I feel like I'm missing something basic here.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd


def select_files(prod_type):
    path = f"\\\\10.10.3.7\\Production\\Test_Folder\\{prod_type}"
    filetypes = (
        ('PDF Files', '*.pdf'),
    )

    filenames = fd.askopenfilenames(
        title='Open files',
        initialdir=path,
        filetypes=filetypes)

    for file in filenames:
        print(file)


class InputFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # setup the grid layout manager
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=3)
        self.__create_widgets()

    def __create_widgets(self):
        # Product
        ttk.Label(self, text='Product:').grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W)
        self.product_type = tk.StringVar()
        self.product_combo = ttk.Combobox(self, width=30, textvariable=self.product_type)
        self.product_combo['values'] = ('Notepad', 'Flat Notecard', 'Folded Notecard', 'Journal')
        self.product_combo.set('Notepad')
        self.product_combo['state'] = 'readonly'
        self.product_combo.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=tk.W)

        # Algorithm:
        ttk.Label(self, text='Algorithm:').grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.W)
        algo_var = tk.StringVar()
        algo_combo = ttk.Combobox(self, width=30)
        algo_combo['values'] = ('panel', 'fuzzy')
        algo_combo.set('panel')
        algo_combo.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=tk.W)

        # Orientation:
        ttk.Label(self, text='Orientation:').grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=tk.W)
        orientation_var = tk.StringVar()
        orientation_combo = ttk.Combobox(self, width=30, textvariable=orientation_var)
        orientation_combo['values'] = ('auto', 'portrait', 'landscape')
        orientation_combo.set('auto')
        orientation_combo.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=tk.W)

        # Margin:
        ttk.Label(self, text='Margin:').grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=tk.W)
        margin = ttk.Entry(self, width=30)
        margin.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=tk.W)

        # Gap:
        ttk.Label(self, text='Gap:').grid(column=0, row=4, sticky=tk.W)
        gap = ttk.Entry(self, width=30)
        gap.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=tk.W)

        # Repeat:
        ttk.Label(self, text='Repeat:').grid(column=0, row=5, sticky=tk.W)
        repeat_number = tk.StringVar()
        repeat = ttk.Spinbox(self, from_=1, to=10, width=30, textvariable=repeat_number)
        repeat.set(1)
        repeat.grid(column=1, row=5, sticky=tk.W)

        for widget in self.winfo_children():
            widget.grid(padx=0, pady=5)


class ButtonFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # setup the grid layout manager
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.__create_widgets()

    def __create_widgets(self):
        ttk.Button(self, text='Select Files', command=self.on_go_pressed).grid(column=0, row=0)
        ttk.Button(self, text='Generate PDF').grid(column=0, row=1)

        for widget in self.winfo_children():
            widget.grid(padx=0, pady=3)

    def on_go_pressed(self):
        select_files(InputFrame.product_type.get())


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("PDF n-up")
        self.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
        self.geometry('400x200')
        self.resizable(0, 0)
        self.attributes('-toolwindow', True)

        # layout on the root window
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=4)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        self.__create_widgets()

    def __create_widgets(self):
        # create the input frame
        input_frame = InputFrame(self)
        input_frame.grid(column=0, row=0)

        # create the button frame
        button_frame = ButtonFrame(self)
        button_frame.grid(column=1, row=0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the product type variable to `ButtonFrame` when you create it, since you create the `ButtonFrame` after creating the `InputFrame`. Here is the code, with changed and added lines marked accordingly:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd


def select_files(prod_type):
    path = f"/home/sam/Pictures/Test/{prod_type}"
    filetypes = (
        ('PDF Files', '*.pdf'),
    )

    filenames = fd.askopenfilenames(
        title='Open files',
        initialdir=path,
        filetypes=filetypes)

    for file in filenames:
        print(file)


class InputFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # setup the grid layout manager
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=3)
        self.__create_widgets()

    def __create_widgets(self):
        # Product
        ttk.Label(self, text='Product:').grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W)
        self.product_type = tk.StringVar()
        self.product_combo = ttk.Combobox(self, width=30, textvariable=self.product_type)
        self.product_combo['values'] = ('Notepad', 'Flat Notecard', 'Folded Notecard', 'Journal')
        self.product_combo.set('Notepad')
        self.product_combo['state'] = 'readonly'
        self.product_combo.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=tk.W)

        # Algorithm:
        ttk.Label(self, text='Algorithm:').grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.W)
        algo_var = tk.StringVar()
        algo_combo = ttk.Combobox(self, width=30)
        algo_combo['values'] = ('panel', 'fuzzy')
        algo_combo.set('panel')
        algo_combo.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=tk.W)

        # Orientation:
        ttk.Label(self, text='Orientation:').grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=tk.W)
        orientation_var = tk.StringVar()
        orientation_combo = ttk.Combobox(self, width=30, textvariable=orientation_var)
        orientation_combo['values'] = ('auto', 'portrait', 'landscape')
        orientation_combo.set('auto')
        orientation_combo.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=tk.W)

        # Margin:
        ttk.Label(self, text='Margin:').grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=tk.W)
        margin = ttk.Entry(self, width=30)
        margin.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=tk.W)

        # Gap:
        ttk.Label(self, text='Gap:').grid(column=0, row=4, sticky=tk.W)
        gap = ttk.Entry(self, width=30)
        gap.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=tk.W)

        # Repeat:
        ttk.Label(self, text='Repeat:').grid(column=0, row=5, sticky=tk.W)
        repeat_number = tk.StringVar()
        repeat = ttk.Spinbox(self, from_=1, to=10, width=30, textvariable=repeat_number)
        repeat.set(1)
        repeat.grid(column=1, row=5, sticky=tk.W)

        for widget in self.winfo_children():
            widget.grid(padx=0, pady=5)


class ButtonFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, product_type): ### EDITED THIS LINE
        super().__init__(parent)
        # setup the grid layout manager
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.product_type = product_type ### ADDED THIS LINE

        self.__create_widgets()

    def __create_widgets(self):
        ttk.Button(self, text='Select Files', command=self.on_go_pressed).grid(column=0, row=0)
        ttk.Button(self, text='Generate PDF').grid(column=0, row=1)

        for widget in self.winfo_children():
            widget.grid(padx=0, pady=3)

    def on_go_pressed(self):
        select_files(self.product_type.get()) ### EDITED THIS LINE


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("PDF n-up")
        self.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
        self.geometry('400x200')
        self.resizable(0, 0)
        # self.attributes('-toolwindow', True)

        # layout on the root window
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=4)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        self.__create_widgets()

    def __create_widgets(self):
        # create the input frame
        input_frame = InputFrame(self)
        input_frame.grid(column=0, row=0)

        # create the button frame
        button_frame = ButtonFrame(self, input_frame.product_type) ### EDITED THIS LINE
        button_frame.grid(column=1, row=0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Notice how in the line `button_frame = ButtonFrame(self, input_frame.product_type)`, I give it `input_frame.product_type` as an argument, so that it can access it any time it wants.

The changes to `ButtonFrame` required for this: I changed the `__init__()` method so that it can receive another argument. It then assigns the value of the `product_type` argument to a variable so that it can use it later. When it calls `select_files()`, it simply uses `self.product_type`.

As to why calling `select_files(InputFrame.product_type.get())` doesn't work: `product_type` is a variable that is created only when `InputFrame` is initialized. In the line above, you reference the class itself, not an *instance* of the class, so it has not been initialized. Therefore, anything that is created in `InputFrame.__init__()` is not defined, becuase `__init__()` wasn't called.

Comment: Much appreciated!!